# Vertical spinning wheel menu in Android

Tags: android, layout, menu

I'm kinnda new in Android. I want to make a vertical spinning wheel menu with images instead of text. Can you please suggest me some ideas how can i implement this? I want to display only **one** Image / menu item(the other menu items not to be displayed). When the menu "shows" i want that the second item from menu to show only a half to suggest to the user that there's another menu item, all what he needs is to slide/scroll.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: i found some examples that i want but i can't reach the code from here : 
http://android-devblog.blogspot.ro/2011/01/android-wheel-update-custom-views-for.html

Comment: https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu

Comment: I copy one form the url your metioned for you: https://github.com/tinybright/android-wheel

Comment: Thanks, do you think is a better idea to use a recycler viewer and cards? A small recycler viewer with cards + 1/2 card dimensions?